# How to force asynchronously save a constant subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mkannotation, pfsubclassing

**Edit 1:** I've restructured my ViewControllers to make it easier to get what I want done.

**Edit 2:** I realized something major was missing while adding notes to my code, another function overrides the first segue.

This ViewController is where the annotation is created; all I need from this view is for the touchMapCoordinates to be transferred to the other ViewController so I can save the PFGeoPoint in an array.

**Edit 3**
After long work on understanding what is going on and simplifying the code, i've came down to the final conclusion based off of [Swift- variable not initialized before use (but it's not used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942742/swift-variable-not-initialized-before-use-but-its-not-used) , that the current method that I'm trying to use will not work in any case or scenario due to it saving Asynchronously. If anyone knows a work around, then you have officially done something that hasn't been done before :).

Error that is showing up is

## Constant 'boi' used before being initialized

**Subclass that is declared in Appdata to be used anywhere within the project**

```
import Foundation
import Parse
import MapKit

class MyAnnotation: PFObject, PFSubclassing, MKAnnotation {

// MARK: - Properties

@NSManaged var location: PFGeoPoint

// MARK: - Initializers

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    super.init()
    self.location = PFGeoPoint(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
    print(location)
    
}

override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
        
        
    }
}

// MARK: - PFSubclassing protocol

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "AnnotationPins"
}

// MARK: - MKAnnotation protocol

var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)
}
```

var title: String? = "Start Topic"

}

**Where the code will all be saved asynchronously together**

```
   } else {
        
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.galleryCameraImage.image!)
        let parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "upload_image.png", data: imageData!)
        let boi : MyAnnotation
        
        let textTitleandText = PFObject(className: "AnnotationPins")
        textTitleandText["textTopic"] = userTopic.text
        textTitleandText["textInformation"] = userText.text
        textTitleandText["userUploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        textTitleandText["imageFile"] = parseImageFile!
        textTitleandText["location"] = boi.location
        
        textTitleandText.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
```

If anyone could help it would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Lets treat your `Location data` as a normal data to be transferred through segues.
 You can use this method to configure your destination View controller variable(same type) that will hold your location data.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   //check your segue name
   if segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier" {
       let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! YourDestinationViewController
       destinationVC.locationVariableInDestinationVC = locationVariableInCurrentVC 
   }

}
```

Above is the simplest way to pass data via segue, you can use the same approach for your location data too.

Hope that helps!!

`Update: Based on your updated code`

Move `func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {}` out of your `handleLongPress` function. `PrepareForSegue` function gets called automatically when there is any navigation happening through segues..

If you want to initiate a segue navigation programatically then assign a identifier to the segue and just call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)`

Comment: `}
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "China" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! AnnotationViewController
            destinationVC.location = MyAnnotation
            
        }
    }`      So within the code I keep  getting the error the Type 'ViewController' has no member location

Comment: you have to add location Variable in your destination view controller that will hold your data. It is like you are assigning a value to a variable which is available in destination view controller.. hope that make sense :)

Comment: ` var locationdata = PFGeoPoint() `
so I have that in the destination viewcontroller but its still not working when i have it set to it = locationdata in the map viewcontroller

Comment: is your `myAnnotation` variable is of type PFGeoPoint? and as you have declared `locationdata` hence it will be  `destinationVC.locationdata = MyAnnotation`

Comment: I've updated the code, with the newer issue, that I've been trying to solve overall, with the myAnnotation being a variable of PFGeoPoint.

Comment: I've updated my code to accurately model my current situation.

Comment: Move `func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {}` out of your `handleLongPress` function. `PrepareForSegue` function gets called automatically when there is any navigation happening through segues.. if you want to initiate a segue navigation programatically then assign a identifier to the segue and just call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)`

Comment: When I put the func prepare for segue outside of the func handle long press, I loose the access to the annotation.

Comment: In that case just move your `var touchMapCoordinate` variable outside of `handleLongPress`, so that you can access in anywhere in your class. Your declaration will be something like this: `var touchMapCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?` as your `annotation.coordinate` is of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. refer this document https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPointAnnotation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPointAnnotation/coordinate

Comment: Well that isn't exactly how the code works, I have the user pick the location of where the annotation will be using the long press gesture. Hence why as soon as I take out the var touchMap, everything depends on everything else. So I'm; in a sense forced to work within those parameters. :(

Comment: I am not getting... the only thing which I am saying is `DECLARE` your `touchMapCoordinate` outside of that function and `INITIALISE` it inside your `handleLongPress` function. this way you will still be able to use your `touchMapCoordinate` inside your `handleLongPress ` function and in `prepareForSegue`. :)

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but could you give me an example of how I would do that within this code?

Answer (score 0):

Over ride `prepareForSegue` method like below.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: 

AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == "SegueID" {
           let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController  
// Create property in destinationView controller & assign required data from here.
       }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've updated my code to accurately model my current situation.